# Install Ruby Using RVM on Virtual Machine Running Debian Failed Silently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, installation, rvm

I've successfully installed a Debian guest operating system on a Vista host using VirtualBox. I'm trying to follow this tutorial(http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you) to install RVM and Ruby. It appears to install ruby successfully, but the terminal will not recognise ruby at all.

Here is the terminal output:

```
user@debian:~$ rvm install 1.9.2
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p136, this may take a while depending on your connection...
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 8612k  100 8612k    0     0   200k      0  0:00:42  0:00:42 --:--:--  328k
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p136 to /home/user/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #extracted to /home/user/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #compiling 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #installing 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - updating #rubygems for /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - updating #rubygems for /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem).
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #importing default gemsets (/home/user/.rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #complete 
user@debian:~$ ruby -v
bash: ruby: command not found
```

I have no idea what went wrong or how to proceed here. I'd appreciate any insight anyone could offer.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it would help (a lot) to read the documentation on [rvm's installation page](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install), particularly the "post install" section. If that doesn't help, do `rvm info` and look for anything anomalous.

Answer (score 6):

Try `rvm use 1.9.2`. Right now it's probably defaulting to the system ruby, and if you don't have a system ruby, well, it's defaulting to nothing.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your rapid reply. You are absolutely correct. This solved my problem instantly. I really appreciate your time. Thanks again. :)

Comment: The `--default` flag has to be set for rvm to set a default. Otherwise, `use` will only exist during the life of that shell.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make this stick between shell sessions: `rvm use --default 1.9.2`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ rvm 1.9.2
```

will do the trick.